# How to send image ( or other large file ) via UDP

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp

I was trying to send a large file, an image between UDP client and server. Server didn't receive any data. After reading documentation I understood single message size limit.
Image is transported in Base64 so dividing it into substrings and sending them separately doesn't seem to be a problem, but I wonder if I'm not kicking out opened door, is there no simpler way ?
Also TCP/IP is not an option in this cause.

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow.  Some of your code would make your question much easier to answer - see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use UDP instead of TCP for unknown reason then you have to live with its limits, i.e. limited message size and that messages can be lost, duplicated and reordered. While your exact code is unknown this means that it likely needs to be even more complex than you describe  since it has to deal with detection of lost messages (and therefore retransmission), detection of reordering and duplicates. The only simplification you likely can do is to use Base64 for encoding the data: UDP has no problem transferring binary data so no encoding into ASCII is needed for transport.

Comment: Thank you. I was just afraid I'd write code which has been already implemented in existing node library. In that case I'm getting to work, once more thanks for help.